# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder

Tags: java, http

I would like to connect some domain with java code. I can connect the domain in the browser as follow:
http://username:password@domain.com

I tryed the following:

```
    String enc = "username" + ":" + "password";
            String encoded = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(loginPassword.getBytes());
URL url = new URL("domain.com");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

I get the error: 401/Unutorized... java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder

Is there any solution I can try?.

Comment: Use a different Base64Encoder class.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Oracle has [announced the removal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm) of those classes in Java 9.

You should not be using classes that are in `sun.*` packages - those classes are not part of the public API of Java and can change in any new Java version.

See [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) in Oracle's documentation.

Instead of using class `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`:

If you are using Java 8, then use class [`java.util.Base64`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) for Base 64 encoding and decoding.

Otherwise, use a third-party library, for example class [`org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) from [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/).

Comment: thank you. using  org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 has solved the problem.