# Java 11 : Patch sun.misc.BASE64Encoder

Tags: java, java-8, base64, deprecated, java-11

This question is not a duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692146/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-sun-misc-base64encoder).

I am trying to update the Java Version (to 11) in my app and one of the libraries in my app uses `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` class, so I inevitably get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

Now, the way to solve would be to use `java.util.Base64` or apache commons as the other answers suggest. However, the problem is, this library belongs to a third party and I don't have the source code for it. There doesn't seem to be a new version that is not using these classes. So, to work around this issue, I did the following:

- Created package `sun.misc`
- Copied both `BASE64Encoder` and `CharacterEncoder` classes in this package

But now, I get a compilation error saying `The package sun.misc conflicts with a package accessible from another module: jdk.unsupported`.

Is there any way to get around this error? If not, can I add a `jar` to the dependencies that contains these classes? I am just trying to make sure these classes are available to that third party library at runtime (either via my own source code or via a jar that bundles these classes in).

Comment: You could always build your own JVM from the OpenJDK sources.   A more practical approach may be to say to the 3rd-party "fix your buggy library to work on Java 11 ... or I stop paying for support".  People should not write their code to depend on internal classes.  Sun / Oracle said it was a bad idea.  There were always alternatives.

Answer (score 13):

The JDK 11 replacement for sun.misc.BASE64Encoder and sun.miscBASE64Decoder is [java.util.Base64.Encoder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html) and [java.util.Base64.Decoder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html).

Typical code in JDK 1.8 would look like:

```
String encoded = new BASE64Encoder().encode(bBytes);
byte[] decoded = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encoded);
```

The JDK 11 replacements which would generate identical values are:

```
import java.util.Base64;
// ...
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bBytes);
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
```

Answer (score 8):

One possible solution to this is you use `--patch-module` argument (if you are flexible in changing your command line). You will need to create a JAR with two class files `BASE64Encoder.class` and `CharacterEncoder.class` inside:

```
base64.jar
    sun
        misc
            BASE64Encoder.class
            CharacterEncoder.class
```

Then you can run your application using the following options:

```
java --patch-module jdk.unsupported=base64.jar ...
```

`--patch-module` will augment the `jdk.unsupported` module with two new classes so now you can use them at runtime.

Comment: How can we use path for base64.jar if its has been located somewhere else than classpath

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error trying to run Spring 5 on Java 11. I can't upgrade to Spring 6 since my company hasn't certified Java 17 yet (another story).

The answer from ZhekaKozlov worked for me, although I had to add `sun/misc/CharacterEncoder.class` to my patch jar.
Also worth noting that adding my `base64.jar` to the classpath had no effect - I had to use the patch-module argument.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error trying to run Spring 5 on Java 11. I can't upgrade to Spring 6 since my company hasn't certified Java 17 yet (another story).
The answer from ZhekaKozlov worked for me, although I had to add sun/misc/CEStreamExhausted.class to my patch jar (I got all the sun classes from rt.jar)
Also worth noting that adding my base64.jar to the classpath had no effect - I had to use the patch-module argument.